# How to config Chrome policies per profile on Linux?

Tags: linux, google-chrome

Some Chrome policies, like [this](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#ExtensionManifestV2Availability), is listed as "Per Profile : Yes".
However, Chrome linux policy help [A]: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9027408
does tell how to config policy at a per profile basis.

I followed [A] and added recommended policies.
`chrome://policy/` lists the configured policies, but there is no option to config them.

How to config the "recommended" per profile policies?